# Nested table in document as pdf

Tags: java, aspose.words

I'm trying to build a document with a nested table using insertHtml-Method from documentBuilder in Aspose Words Java (Version 20.12).

When i create a docx file everthing looks fine, but as a pdf the table runs out of the sheet.

My code looks like following:

```
Document doc = new Document();
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);
builder.insertHtml("<table border=\"1\" style=\"width: 100%;\"><tbody><tr><td style=\"width: 20%;\">A</td><td><table border=\"1\" style=\"width: 100%;\"><tbody><tr><td style=\"width: 20%;\">1</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr><tr><td>B</td><td>C</td></tr></tbody></table>", true);
doc.updateTableLayout();
doc.save("inner_table.pdf", SaveFormat.PDF);
doc.save("inner_table.docx", SaveFormat.DOCX);
```

Does anyone knows why this happen? Is it a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Note that it is normally not recommended to call [Document.updateTableLayout()](https://apireference.aspose.com/words/java/com.aspose.words/Document#updateTableLayout()) method.
In your case, if remove call of this method, the table looks good in both DOCX and PDF output.

Comment: Sure, i could remove the call and everything works fine. But in which cases i have to call updateTableLayout? And why do the call of updateTableLayout break my table in pdf? I my opinion the call must not break the table but leave it as it is in this case.

Comment: In MS Word documents tables normally have table grid - precalculated columns widths. But in some cases (like import from HTML) table grid is not calculated. updateTableLayout method is an attempt to calculate table grid like MS Word does, but since MS Word logic is not always straightforward, the method does not give accurate result. In your particular case the algorithm does not work properly with nested tables.

Comment: Upon export to fixed-page formats, like pdf, xps etc, Aspose.Words recalculates table grid if it does not exist (another algorithm is used thought) so normally it is not required to updateTableLayout.